# Calling FormApp within doGet(e) function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am relatively new to scripting, so please be kind.

I am trying to create a function bound to a Form within Google Apps, including a webapp which captures 3 variables (requestNum, approverNum, and status) and obtains various other information from the FormApp (e.g titles, responses, etc).

I am receiving -  **TypeError: Cannot call method "getId" of null** on line 3 of the below code (which is bound to the Form).

Any guidance in being able to call form information from within the doGet function is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

```
  function doGet(e){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formId = form.getId();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var d = new Date();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT+11", "MMM dd yyyy");
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO approvals '
      + '(formId, requestNum, approverNum, status, date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  stmt.setString(1, formId);
  stmt.setString(2, e.parameter.requestNum);
  stmt.setString(3, e.parameter.approverNum);
  stmt.setString(4, e.parameter.status);
  stmt.setString(5, d);
  stmt.execute();

  var nextApproverNum = e.parameter.approverNum + 1;
  var answer = e.parameter.status;
  var requestNum = e.parameter.requestNum;
  var nextApproverEmail = e.parameter.reply;

  var titles = [];
  for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  titles.push(items[i].getTitle());
  }

  var responses = [];
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemResponses = formResponses[requestNum-1].getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    responses.push(itemResponses[j].getResponse());
  }
  ....etc
```

Comment: As written [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getActiveForm()) getId() will only work if the form to which the script is container-bound. In other words this works only when you create the script in the form, not in a separate script or responses sheet.

Comment: If your script is created in that form, try running first three lines of the code separately.

Comment: @AkshinJalilov - understand the script must be bound to the Form - it currently resides within the Form script.  I have tested running the three lines of code manually and it works without issue.  The problem arises when the function is run **using the webapp** (I have settings set to 'executed the app as me' and 'can be accessed by anyone, including anonymous'.  I require data from users, which I am obtaining through a link - hence the reason it needs it to be run through the webapp.  Many thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Since it appears not to work with the webapp, I have tried slightly amended code to capture the formId in the link, in order to run openById(e.parameter.formId). However now I receive the error: **You do not have permission to call openById**

Comment: worst case scenario I can send the form titles and responses to an external database and pull from there, but would prefer not in this instance.

Comment: When running a webapp, there is no "active form". You should be able to open by id iff the script runs as you (or at least by someone able to edit the form).

Comment: @Mogsdad thanks for the response.  Unfortunately despite running the webapp as me, I continue to receive the permission error.  This is incredibly frustrating, as I don't see any reasons why it should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the right conditions for access, the code you're having problems with works. You should review the settings you've used for publishing as a web app.

This snippet focuses just on the issue you've brought up, and it works as expected:

```
function doGet(e){
//  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); // TypeError: Cannot call method "getId" of null.
  var form = FormApp.openById('17lTBrLmQxggVADlnPC6DgTZf1f2sCEA1Rc9ZIpBu_uQ');
  var formId = form.getId();
  var items = form.getItems();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Form contains "+items.length+"items.");
}
```

[image: deploy]

Comment: Turns out I had '@OnlyCurrentDoc' buried in my code from an earlier script.  Apologies for the oversight.